# Can I receive USD 1500 from a cousin in USA to my account in India

Tags: taxes, india, international-transfer, wire-transfer

Please let me know if I can receive USD 1500 from a cousin from USA to my savings account in India.

Comment: People send money around the world all the time. A child working in one country, but wanting to help parents elsewhere. Are you asking about any taxes, gift or income? Can you edit to spell out exactly what the question is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You would need to give your Bank Account, Bank Name along with SWIFT BIC. This information will be available on the website or the Branch.

Note depending on why the payment is being made to you, it may be taxable to you in India.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal to receive the money from your friend sitting in US as it will attract lesser charges(only 1% of the total amount which is $15 in your case on other hand bank will charge you at least 3%) as compared to direct back transfer.

Comment: What _rate_ of exchange does PayPal offer, as compared to various banks as well as various services such as Money2India, Remit2India, Xoom, etc? I have never been charged 3% as a transfer fee by these services (though the exchange rate is a little worse than the LIBOR rate), whereas international wire transfers cost $40 at my bank.and I don't get the LIBOR rate either.

Answer (score -3):

An alternative method that may work out cheaper *and* faster (or it may not) is Bitcoin.

**Step one**
Sign up for an account with an Bitcoin exchange in India and add your bank details.
Here is one that is well regarded:
https://btcxindia.com/

**Step two**
Ask your cousin to set up an account with a Bitcoin exchange in the USA.
Here is one that is well regarded:
https://coinbase.com/

**Step three**
Give your cousin your Bitcoin address (it is a long string of numbers and letters beginning with a 1 and looks something like this -  14PeKoEB5GMMzN7JMzhWkfHjVryEAsSGwh)

**Step four**
Exchange your bitcoins for Indian Rupee using btcxindia & request withdrawal.

Comment: Curious why this answer got downvoted. It may not be the best method in many respects, but it seems like a valid answer.